# Detecting ontouchstart instantly

Tags: javascript, touch-event

I'm making a platformer HTML game and have a problem that the player doesn't instantly move after I trigger the touch event. When I start pressing the button I have to wait 1-2 seconds till the player starts moving

I've also had other games with the same problem where I tried other methods fixing it.

Here's the code:

```html
<div id="stage">
    <div id="player"></div>
    <div id="block"></div>
    <button ontouchstart="config.speedX = -1" ontouchend="config.speedX = 0" id="left"></button>
    <button ontouchstart="config.speedX = 1" ontouchend="config.speedX = 0" id="right"></button>
</div>
```

```js
let config = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    speedX: 0,
    speedY: 0
};

let gameloop = setInterval(() => {
    player.style.left = config.x + "px";
    player.style.bottom = config.y + "px";
    config.x += config.speedX;
    config.y += config.speedY;
}, 20);
```

Comment: What happens if you change it from a `<button>` element to a `<div>` element?

Comment: Well, it's got to wait at least 20 ms for the loop to run before it picks up on the change. Also `<button>` elements should specify the `type`; in your case, I suggest adding `type="button"` so that nothing is submitted.

Comment: @Samathingamajig That does nothing

Comment: @HereticMonkey The 20ms timeout isn't really the case, in one of my other games I had a lower timeout and still the same touch event delay

Comment: i think you need to add `sleep()`, check this for how to use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep